# Change Active/clicked background color react-bootstrap button

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

Using `react-bootstrap` Button, my `CSS` overwrote the hover background color, but it won't handle the active, I'm thinking it is not an `'active'`, but the documentation says there is an `'active'` attribute.

How can I control the background color of the button with the `CSS`:
the `"&[active]"` attribute selector does not work, neither does the `"&:active"`.

How can I make the Button so it doesn't apply the new background color when it is clicked. I assume this is coming from the default `btn` styles in `bootstrap`, I just want to override it.

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  buyButton:{
    "&[active]": {
      backgroundColor: "#69059F",
    },
    backgroundColor: "#69059F",
    paddingTop: "10px",
    marginTop: "10px",
    borderRadius: "10px",        
    border: "none",          
    "&:hover": {
      backgroundColor: "#69059F" ,
    }       
  }    
}));
```

Comment: Did you managed to do this? How did you do it? I am having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have to override the buttons default scss calls. So, for example if you wanted to change all primary buttons when active/clicked it would look something like this:

```
index.css

.btn-primary:active {
  --bs-btn-active-bg:#ff79c6;
  --bs-btn-active-border-color: #ff79c6;
  --bs-btn-active-color: #44475a;
}
```